# empty .htaccess file breaks site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been trying to get some url rewrites to work with .htaccess after moving a site to a new host.

Nothing seemed to work, so in frustration I removed all the code from the file, uploading a blank .htaccess file to the server.  The Result: **FORBIDDEN**.

Is this a problem with the server config?  How do I go about addressing it.

**EDIT**

Ok, so I got it to work.  I think it must have had something to do with the encoding or format (or whatever) of the .htaccess file itself.  I origionally suspected something like this and messed with a bunch of stuff in notepad++, and thought I ruled that out.  Earlier, in desperation, I recreated the file in regular notepad and it worked.

Thank you all for your insights...

Comment: When you remove empty .htaccess file from new host, does it work fine after that?

Comment: Yes.  The site works fine (minus the rewrite) until I upload a .htaccess file.  Deleting the file restores the site

Comment: do you control the server configuration?  do you have root privileges on the box?  Can you check the error log to verify that the problem is that you need to alter "AllowOverride"?

Comment: @Galled I have verified that mod_rewrite is in fact enabled.  I think that this should be irrelevant to my question, since the .htaccess file breaks the site even without using mod_rewrite.

Comment: @stew - unfortunately I do not.  I can contact them (a local company) but I do not want to until I know what i'm talking about.  I'm not familiar with AllowOverride and will be reading up on that now...

Comment: AllowOverride is a change that would need to be made to the apache configuration probably by the server admin.  The error logs would verify that this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that being empty of not will make the difference. IMHO this is happening because the virtualhost is not allowing you to `override` in your *document root*

try adding this

```
<Directory "/var/www/example.com">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

where `/var/www/example.com` is the path to your *document root*

Comment: hmmm... so far i'm not having any luck with this.  I'll keep tinkering with it though

Comment: if one is able to alter the apache configuration one should NOT be using .htaccess.  you should just make the changes you need to make in the apache configuration.  .htaccess can be a seucrity problem and it is a definite performance problem (Now for every file access in /var/www/example.com apache needs to look for .htaccess files in every directory up to the document root for ever request)

Comment: I do not control server config.  Performance is not a huge issue.  Its a small, mostly static site & moves rather quickly.  The rewrite is just to redirect the olddomain/page to newdomain/page.

Comment: right. lets keep the scope here: lets first fix the .htaccess issue and then we worry about performace issues.
@ZachL. are you sure do don't have any setting in your hosting panel that is preventing you of doing these kind of changes?

Comment: Good question gabriel.  I was only given ftp access, I will have to ask for control panel access.  Thank you for your assistance so far.  Unfortunately I have to run out for a couple hours now.  I'll check this out when I get back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be related but have you insured that you have an index page (like `index.html` or similar) and in your `<Directory>` tag of your Apache's configuration file have the directive `Options All -Indexes`?

Have you tried with [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/) options?

Comment: I have an index.php.  I don't have access to the apache config files, but with .htaccess I tried the `<Directory>` code from Gabriel's answer (w/ appropriate doc. root) as well as some stuff from the link you sent.  Alas, no matter what I do, the site 403's when I put up the .htaccess